# My view does not redirect after processing a form. Used HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: django, forms, redirect

I am new to Django and I am trying to use custom forms. My problem is that my form does not do anything after I submit it.

I am following the documentation here:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/

I have the following files:

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class TestForm(forms.Form):

    text = forms.CharField(label='Text', max_length=50)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'home'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('test', views.test_view, name='test')
]
```

views.py:

```
def index(request):

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)

def test_view(request):
   
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        form = TestForm(request.POST)      
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('home:index')

    else:
        form = TestForm()

    return render(request, 'test.html', context={'form':form, 'text':'No text yet.',})
```

template: test.html

```
<div>
    <form action="home:club-invite" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form> 
    
    <hr>

    <p>Your text: {{ text }}</p>

</div>
```

The **problem** is that the Submit button does nothing. I was expecting a redirect to the *index* page. But here is no error, no subsequent http request or redirect, nothing...
Am I missing something here?

PS:I also tried `return redirect('home:index')`. Still no success.

Comment: `action="home:club-invite"` is there any function `club-invite`?

Comment: You are right, I had completely missed that. changed it to `action="test"`. Now it works.

Comment: The best way to make that, is using template tags. The template tag "url" is built-in on django.
action="{% url 'home:test' %}"